# Trim jquery td table

Tags: jquery, html

```
<table id="table">
 <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Apellido</th>
        <th>Edad</th>
    </tr>
 </thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Juan</td>
        <td class="td_apellido">   Perez   </td><!-- espacios en blanco necesito retirarlos-->
        <td>25</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Jorge</td>
        <td class="td_apellido">   Aguilar   </td><!-- espacios en blanco necesito retirarlos-->
        <td>15</td>
    </tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

Tengo un td con espacios en blanco lo cual he intentado usar $.trim pero sin resultados:

```
$("#table").find("tbody").find("td").each(function(){ 
    if ($(this).attr("class") == "td_apellido") {
        $(this).text().trim();
    }
 });
```

Comment: la funcion trim() ignora los espacios del medio ejemplo "___De__la __cruz___ ", lo dejaria "De__la __cruz ", no le importa los espacios del centro. tenia la misma duda. espero haberte ayudado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solo te falta asignar el resultado del trim de vuelta a la celda original:

```js
$("#table").find("tbody").find("td").each(function(){ 
    if ($(this).attr("class") == "td_apellido") {
       $(this).text($(this).text().trim());
    }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
 <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Apellido</th>
        <th>Edad</th>
    </tr>
 </thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Juan</td>
        <td class="td_apellido">   Perez   </td><!-- espacios en blanco necesito retirarlos-->
        <td>25</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Jorge</td>
        <td class="td_apellido">   Aguilar   </td><!-- espacios en blanco necesito retirarlos-->
        <td>15</td>
    </tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: A partir de tu respuesta aprendí la ventaja de rendimiento de usar find() en lugar de selectores complejos. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

También podrías crear una función independiente que quite los espacios en blanco.

```
function quitarEspacios($cadena){
$cadena = str_replace(' ', '', $cadena);
return $cadena;
}
```

Comment: Ten en cuenta que `jQuery.trim` quita más que sólo espacios en blanco, también elimina otros separadores como saltos de línea o tabuladores. Además, `trim` los elimina de los laterales, mientras que la función que incluyes los borra de todos lados lo cual puede crear problemas. Por ejemplo: la frase "     Hola Gonzalo   " con `trim` quedaría "Hola Gonzalo", pero con tu función queda "HolaGonzalo".

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo contigo, en este caso me deje guiar por el ejemplo de los apellidos que se mostraron en la pregunta, me faltó tomar en cuenta (si se da el caso) de un apellido como "De La Cruz" o algo similar.